# How to get by default select value in dropdown in Edit mode laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In edit mode my selecte dropdown like this.

```
<select  name="comic_publisher" id="publishers" >
            @foreach($group as $team)
                <option value="{{$team['group_id']}}">{{$team['comic_group_name']}}</option>
            @endforeach
      </select>
```

and I want like if I edit the record the selected value associated with that record is by default here should be selected.

I am stuck with the little issue, can anyone please help me how to do that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you're trying to do ? Like giving an exemple of what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve first database inserted value, and then check that value with all options if match found you can select like,

```
$db_selected_value = "2"; // retrieved data
<select name="comic_publisher" id="publishers" >
        @foreach($group as $team)
            <option value="{{$team['group_id']}}" @if($db_selected_value == $team['group_id']) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>{{$team['comic_group_name']}}</option>
        @endforeach
  </select>
```

here, `@if($db_selected_value == $team['group_id']) {{ 'selected' }} @endif` this line matches your old selected value to all the other. and selected selects

Comment: Welcome brother if it solved your issue then do not forget to mark answer as right answer with upvote.

Comment: Thank a lot brother. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with adding `selected` key word to the option if it refers the old value, like this :

```
<select  name="comic_publisher" id="publishers" >
    @foreach($group as $team)
        <option value="{{$team['group_id']}}" {{ $oldGroupId == $team['group_id'] ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$team['comic_group_name']}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

PS : you have to replece the `$oldGroupId` by the value of the edited element group id

Answer (score 1):

```
<select  name="comic_publisher" id="publishers" >
        @foreach($group as $team)
            <option value="{{$team['group_id']}}" 
@if ($team['group_id'] == $someIdValueToBeSelectFromBacked ) {
'selected' }
 @endif>{{$team['comic_group_name']}}</option>
        @endforeach
  </select>
```